# Draw a line chart in ggplot using variables in columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataset is organized in this way:

```
factor <- c("group1", "group2", "group2")
X <- c("A", "B", "C")
V1 <- c(1:3)
V2 <- c(7:9)
V3 <- c(13:15)

df <- data.frame(factor, X, V1, V2, V3)
df
  factor X V1 V2 V3
1 group1 A  1  7 13
2 group2 B  2  8 14
3 group2 C  3  9 15
```

I would like to represent a line chart where:

- The X axis represents X (A, B, C)
- The Y axis represents values from V1, V2, and V3
- I want to represent in a single chart these three lines, one per each variable (V1, V2, V3).
- I want to color parts of each line differently according to factor variable, so that a single line (V1 for instance) is partly represented by two colors (let's say red group1 and green group2).

Comment: What prevents you to do so? Did you checked `plot`, `lines`, `ggplot2` already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely going to want to `tidy` your data first -- this has to be a duplicate, but couldn't find one quickly...

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -factor, -X) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = X, y = value, group = key, color = factor)) +
  geom_line(size = 2)
```

[image: plot]